# Rigify Warping my Arms

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

After having great success with a Rigify workflow on several projects, I'm suddenly unable to get my arms to look correct. I've tried to trace back anything I've changed about my workflow but nothing seems to be fixing it.

In general, I'm looking to create a human metarig, place an model over it, generate a rig and parent with automatic weights. I'm making sure that there is a bend in the elbows to ensure they're bending in the right direction, this is not my issue. It seems that the automatic weighting is making the arms bend in an unnatural way. While I could fix the weight-painting manually, I have to rig many models to this skeleton for a project, and I also know from experience that this part usually works.

My only clue is that previous models that have been successful have had the arms straightened in their rest position. Again, I don't think anything changed from me generating a human metarig and using the default rig (sometimes with updated face, sometimes without), so I'm curious why I have this discrepancy. I've looked at all of the properties in the Item, Data, and Bone panels and I don't find anything different. I don't think this changed with versions, as I had success with 3.6 creations and I've tested in 3.3 and 3.5 just to make sure.

I've included an example of a successful character and the one I'm trying to fix. I stripped the files down rather quickly so there's likely a lot of extra information left in the outliner/keyframes.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Guxf8byKLRKPCLQ0ILbrsqQE2fqzdafM?usp=sharing

[image: my issue]

[image: a correctly rigged character from a month ago]

Comment: The normals of the arm meshes are inverted, switch to Edit mode and Shift N?